# how to make php variables show in loaded content

Tags: php, jquery

tried to ask this question earlier but made a total mess of it. so thought i'd try it again but clearer this time.

how can you get php variables to display in loaded content using JQuery?

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $('#parent').load('loaded.php #child', {},function(){

    });

        });

});
</script>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
$test = "this should display php string";
$_SESSION['another'] = "Session variable String";

echo ' tests to see if they work below <br>';
echo $test."<br>";
echo $_SESSION['another']."<br><br>";
?>
<button name="clickMe" id="clickMe" class="clickMe">Click me</button>
<div class="parent" name="parent" id="parent" style="background-color:yellow; height:200px; width:200px;">
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

loaded.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div name="child" id="child" class="child">

          <p1> html loads fine..</p1><br>
         <?php echo $test ?><br>
         <?php echo $_SESSION['another'] ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: start the session and define the variable(s)

Comment: The `#child` needs to be removed from the URL. If you want something specific returned use a parameter on the request and have the requesting page only serve that bit. You also should have the `<body>` after the closing `head`.

Comment: nocked this up  on the quick, ill try these sugestions in a bit when im free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Fred -ii- in the comments, you only have to fetch the session in your index.php file to do this.

If you want to get a part of another web page inside index.php :

Your `index.php` should contain this call :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $('#parent').load('loaded.php'); // No need for additional parameters
    });
});
```

You don't need to select a part of the HTML, return just what you need :

`loaded.php` :

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<p>Example text</p>
<?php echo $_SESSION['another'] ?>
```

Comment: in the main project im using this in ill be sending select parts of the loaded.php page, to the index page (different forms to fill the parent depending on the need...)

Comment: your right though putting the session_start in the part of the loaded page i need seems to do the trick, thanks!  once again the solution is blindingly obvious once you know it!

Comment: this works well but how would it differ for the non session variable? - just to complete the learning?

Comment: sorted it - you'd just put the regular variables in the same page as the loaded content (loaded.php), i had mine loaded from elsewhere which was un-necessary.